# VLC video playback is trimmed and blacked out

Tags: kubuntu, video, 15.10, kde, vlc

I am using Kubuntu 15.10 and recently I have updated the version to the latest backport version. But soon after the update VLC has started making weird output. VLC is cropping out the video and the rest of area is blacked out. Also mouse pointer turns invisible upon hovering, the player has gone reckless.

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Qt `5.5.x` bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48321

You'll have to disable the `"Integrate video in interface"` option in `Tools -> Preferences -> Interface` until it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your update changed VLC's choice of video output, or broke the one VLC was using. Luckily, there are few you can try:

- Go to `Tools->Preferences` (If the menus are hidden behind a video gone wild, stop playback, or start vlc from menu or terminal without specifying a file to be played back)
- In the bottom left of the Preferences windows, make sure `Show settings: All` is selected.
- In the tree that is now visible, choose `Video->Output modules`
- Select a different item from the `Video output module` dropdown.
- Restart VLC, try playback.
- Repeat until you find a video output that works.