# Vlc Crops video

Tags: 16.04, video, vlc

Vlc isn't working properly on my system. When I open any video the screen gets cut and only cropped part of the video gets played. Issue persists even if I go Full Screen. While the stock video player runs well.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with vlc 2.2.2 weatherwax.

Below is the screenshot

[Vlc Cuts screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a5p7.png)

Comment: Graphics card and drivers you may eventually installed?

Comment: Those drivers are built in right.. and I have also installed GPU drivers from Intel Graphics tool but the issue still occurs...

 Furthermore, this guy had the same problem as me and the solution works "https://askubuntu.com/questions/729938/vlc-video-playback-is-trimmed-and-blacked-out " but now the video plays in a separate tab than VLC. Is there any way to integrate the video into the vlc tab itself

Comment: What do you mean with "plays in a separate tab"?

Comment: If i untick the highlighted box as marked in the below image, then the vlc plays in a separate window of VLC and everything works smoothly. exept that everytime 2 vlc windows are open.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jK6etrOGvr40gKKRC1L5nOIrsdpMEP27/view